# Platform independent library for graphics-related matrix calculations in C#

Tags: library, c#, matrix, numerical-analysis

For a platform independent C# phone application (built using Xamarin), I am searching for a small matrix library which supports 3D graphics related operations.

Required operations are:

- Multiplication
- Inverse
- Creating projection matrices
- Creating view matrices
- Creating rotation/translation/scale matrices
- Transforming a vector by a given matrix

While I know that I can implement these operations myself, I would prefer using an existing library for this.

Does such a library exist?

Background: We try to avoid full graphic engines like Monogame, because the are fairly unstable on phones. Instead, we use fake 3D by just positioning flat UI-elements according to the result of some matrix calculations, which is completely sufficient for our purpose.